# 32676 is being returned by printf. Please make me understand as to why the output of the following is not 11

Tags: c, printf

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    void main()
    {
    int a,b,p;
    printf("Enter values of a and b");
    scanf("%d%d", &a, &b);
    p=printf("a=%d b=%d p=%d",a,b, p);
    }
```

This is the code for my question. Consider the inputs as a=2 and b=3.

Comment: Why `11` and not `42`? And I suggest you to re-read your program carefully.

Comment: You are trying to print `p` before you have assigned a value to it.

Comment: As I understand printf returns the value of total number of characters it has printed. I counted it to be 11. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort shown. Even forgotten letters in the format string. All other questions have been answered here million times or can be answered by reading any C book

Comment: `a=%` --> `a=%d`

Comment: And we have no idea what you are giving it as an input.

Comment: Thanks a lot @PaulR. I changed the code and now it is alright. I hadn't expected an answer so fast.

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
p=printf("a=% b=%d p=%d",a,b, p);
```

to:

```
p = printf("a=%d b=%d\n", a, b); // <<< fix format string
printf("p=%d\n", p);             // <<< print `p` *after* you have assigned a value to it
```

***Please also enable compiler warnings from this day forward - any good compiler would have pointed out all of the above errors to you at compile-time.***